# Medium Blog - Naming

Tags: discussion, blog

I'm in the process of moving our old blog over to a new platform (Medium) as part of our birthday celebrations. In doing so, I'm reconsidering the name, which is currently The Magrathean Forges. That's an OK name, but it could certainly be better.

Has anyone got any other suggestions for names?

Comment: Context for move: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/2507/28

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The temporary name I put in while we figure out another, for voting:

## Universe Factory

Comment: I really like this name even if it was just meant to be temporary.

Answer (score 7):

Clever names are fun, and one of my favorites since the first time we discussed this topic is *Daedalus' Workshop*

That said there is a lot are a lot of positives to using something simple (as we chose to do with the chatroom) and go with *The world builders' blog*

Makes it abundantly obvious what the purpose/intent of the site is.

Comment: I randomly sampled a few of the blogs there and "name: short description" is a common format.  So we can have a clever name and then have the tag line say something that includes "the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange community" or some such.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Works for me

Comment: I like it, but I think you switched the "ae" to "ea" in "Daedalus".

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice that when I voted.  My vote presumes correct spelling. :-)

Comment: Doh.  You'd think a certain mod from writers would have noticed that...

Comment: It's *Writers*, not *Proofreaders*.  That's the best I can come up with, anyway.  That, and insufficient caffeine at the time. :-)

Comment: Friendly amendment: Title is Daedalus' Workshop (as you proposed); subtitle is "blog of the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange community".

Answer (score 0):

Just to have it here for voting, ArtOfCode's original name:

**The Magrathean Forges**

Answer (score -2):

Just to provide some alternative which is 1) short and 2) a clear reference to WB.

## The Built Worlds

Answer (score -3):

### World Building Stack Exchange Community Blog

It is unfortunate that blog overflow is being taken down. To help make sure that this blog stays connected with this site, I think we should name it after this site. That also helps with search engines, since then the sites would be more likely to be connected.